# Show the data from session to label

Tags: .net

I used

```
Session["EmpName"] = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString[1]);
lblEmployeeName.Text = Session["EmpName"].ToString;
```

to show the data in label from session but it shows following error:

> Cannot Convert Method Group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'string'.

Tell me any solution...

Comment: you forgot the brackets: `.ToString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lblEmployeeName.Text = Session["EmpName"].ToString;
```

should be:

```
lblEmployeeName.Text = Session["EmpName"].ToString();
```

even better would be, (this will not crash if the Session["EmpName"] is null):

```
string empName= Session["EmpName"] as string;
if (empName != null)
{
    lblEmployeeName.Text = empName;
}
else
{
    // Session expired?
}
```

An extra note:

```
Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString[1]);
```

You should look for a specific value, you can't be sure of the order from the QueryString values! And the Request.QueryString[1] returns a string. No need for convert.

```
Request.QueryString["Value"];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

Session["EmpName"] = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["1"]);

lblEmployeeName.Text =Convert.ToString(Session["EmpName"]);